# How to get kernel executable pages in Volatility (linux memory)?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, computer-forensics, volatility

I have a memory dump of Linux system.
I am trying to find all the executable pages in memory belonging to the kernel. How can I do that using Volatility/Rekall?